# CMD: Print the password of current user

Tags: cmd, scripting, passwords

In the cmd prompt, is there a command I can run to display the password of the currently logged in user?

My usage scenario is this. I have an arbitrary bat script that runs 3 programs sequentially:

```
REM do some work
foo.exe
REM do some more work
```

Half way through foo.exe, it prompts for the current user's password before continuing. This defeats the purpose of scripting, which is automation because after kicking off the script, I must check back half way to enter the password.

Solution 1:
Hard code the password into script and pipe it.

```
REM do some work
echo hard.coded.password | foo.exe
REM do some more work
```

This approach has 2 problems right away:

1. Putting pwd in a bat file is insecure.
2. Others can't run the script because each has a different pwd.

So ideally, I'd like to do:

```
REM do some work
command-that-prints-current-user-pwd-to-output | foo.exe
REM do some more work
```

This way, password is not hard coded in the script, therefore making it more safe and shareable.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. Only the user knows the password. Windows doesn't.

Passwords are one way hashed and the hash is stored not the password. Being one way it can't be reversed. When you enter a password it is hashed and the hashes compared.